# BlogEngine.Net post to Root Domain from virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web, blogengine.net

I've developed a site with ASP.Net and implemented BlogEngine.Net under a virtual directory. The site is...

[www.oxphysio.co.uk](http://www.oxphysio.co.uk/news)

and the BlogEngine.Net is implemented under

[www.oxphysio.co.uk/news](http://www.oxphysio.co.uk/news)

I want to be able to have a user post from BlogEngine.Net 2.8 to the main site even though BlogEngine is under a seperate virtual directory. My first thought is URL Rewriting. Has anyone implemented this or can anyone come up with a different suggestion?

Comment: When you say post, do you mean post an article to the main site or post an HTML form?  Could you also please provide more background on what this will accomplish for you?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The main site is a completely seperate beast with it's own members area, but I want the blog engine to allow users to create pages for the site that can go anywhere they like under the root, as well as blog articles for the news section that blog engine virtual directory is at. Make sense?

Comment: An example... It's a physiotherapy site so I want the members to be able to create say a page with Pilates class times and be able to maintain it under say www.oxphysio.co.uk/pilates/classes but also add a news blog when required under the normal www.oxphysio.co.uk/news/new-physio-joined-today

Answer (score 0):

I don't think BlogEngine is the solution you are looking for.  It sounds like you need a Content Management System (CMS) with a blog component.  If you try to use BlogEngine for this you are trying to turn blog software into a CMS.  BlogEngine is not designed for that.

Some .net CMS Systems

- [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/)
- [Umbraco](https://umbraco.com/)

Comment: I don't know orchard, I'll have a look at that but I know umbraco and that would be an extremely heavy duty solution and rewrite or reorganisation. The main website is just normal pages but there are bespoke elements of it already developed for managing appointments amongst other thing in the forms authenticated area and I just want an additional news blogging area but the potential to add or maintain a few extra pages under the main site that would be visible to everyone.